# JSP - passing a variable to a method from forEach loop

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, foreach

I am trying to pass value in variable 'i' from the forEach loop to the parameter of method get(). I tried the below mentioned methods. But I was not successful.

Request you to help me in passing the variable i to the method get().

**Try 1:**

                           ${documentFactory.getTypeFor(entity.metadata()).flatten().getFieldsData().get(i).getType().resolve().getPrimitiveType()}

**Try 2:**

                           ${documentFactory.getTypeFor(entity.metadata()).flatten().getFieldsData().get(${i}).getType().resolve().getPrimitiveType()}

**Try 3:**

                           ${documentFactory.getTypeFor(entity.metadata()).flatten().getFieldsData().get(i).getType().resolve().getPrimitiveType()}

**Try 4:**

                           ${documentFactory.getTypeFor(entity.metadata()).flatten().getFieldsData().get(i-1).getType().resolve().getPrimitiveType()}

**Try 5:**

```
<c:forEach begin="1" end= "${documentFactory.getTypeFor(entity.metadata()).flatten().getFieldsData().size()}" var="i">

${documentFactory.getTypeFor(entity.metadata()).flatten().getFieldsData().get(${i}-1).getType().resolve().getPrimitiveType()}

</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Is this Java or JQuery?  What is that $ dollar sign doing there?

Comment: Its a JSP  with JSTL tags. Back end is Java.

Comment: Can you show the entire `foreach` loop?

Comment: I did post it and I don't know why the loop is not shown in the question :| Have posted the same below. 
 <c:forEach begin="1" end= "${documentFactory.getTypeFor(entity.metadata()).flatten().getFieldsData().size()}" var="i">
                            ${documentFactory.getTypeFor(entity.metadata()).flatten().getFieldsData().get(i).getType().resolve().getPrimitiveType()}
</c:forEach>

Comment: whats the error that you are getting?

Comment: Uncaught exception { org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/HomePage.jsp at line 72
    70:                                         <!--SDL type fetching logic -->
    71:                                        <c:forEach begin="1" end= "${documentFactory.getTypeFor(entity.metadata()).flatten().getFieldsData().size()}" var="i">
    72:                                        ${documentFactory.getTypeFor(entity.metadata()).flatten().getFieldsData().get(i).getType().resolve().getPrimitiveType()}
    73:  /c:forEach>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using for each `items`?

```
<c:forEach items="${documentFactory.getTypeFor(entity.metadata()).flatten().getFieldsData()}" var='data'>
    ${data.getType().resolve().getPrimitiveType()}
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I will try that and will reply back :)

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the end and begin values in the variables as:

```
<% 
   int begin = 1;
   int end = ${documentFactory.getTypeFor(entity.metadata()).flatten().getFieldsData().size()};
%>

<c:forEach var="i" begin="<%=begin %>" end= "<%=end %>" >
   ${documentFactory.getTypeFor(entity.metadata()).flatten().getFieldsData().get(${i}-1).getType().resolve().getPrimitiveType()}
</c:forEach>
```

I have done this because i think the problem is in the `end` parameter.

If possible check by placing direct value in the `end` parameter as

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end= "10" >
   <span>${i}</span>
</c:forEach>
```

Just for the check.

Let me know if anything happens or for any query.

Comment: I tried this -> <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end= "10" >
   <span>${i}</span>
</c:forEach>  before too and it works fine. It was causing the error in the above statement that I posted in my question